# IIS 10 - make domain user server manager

Tags: iis, iis-10

Is there a way to make a non-privileged domain user (who is not in the Administrator group of the server nor in Domain Administrator group) server manager of IIS 10 (Win Server 2016)? I only managed to make that user site administrator.
Searching on the internet I found some guidelines about IIS 7 or incomplete informations...I did not even understand if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

step-by-step here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/leesab/2014/07/30/delegating-iis-administration-to-domain-users-non-administrators/

Regards,

Comment: That is the guide I followed to make the domain user site administrator. But, as far as I understood, that user is not server administrator, he is limited to the single site. For example, I do not think that the user can create a new site.

Comment: You are correct, this step-by-step will delegate at app/site leve, not ad server leve like you asked.